# what are some Lower bound for finding large fourier coefficients of boolean function (above a threshold)?

Tags: fourier-analysis, sample-complexity

Is there some known lower bounds for estimating large fourier coefficients of boolean functions? And were there any comparison of tightness with the upper bound of Goldreich Levin algorithm?